# Using Selected Values to Filter Data with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i want to filter my output based on the selected value in a  component:

```
<select ng-model="showGroup.group">
   <option value="A">A</option>
   <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
```

My Data which i want to show:

```
  {
    "name" : "Steve",
    "group" : "A"
  },
  {
    "name" : "Bob",
    "group" : "B"
  },
  {
    "name" : "Peter",
    "group" : "B"
  },
```

If a "A" is selected then i should show only Steve and if "B" is selected it should show Bob and Peter!

My Outputcode:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
      <td>{{person.name | filter:showGroup}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The Controller only gets the data from a JSON file.

Why this is not working?
With an `<input>` element it works fine?!

Do I need to write my own filter? How do i do that?

Comment: filter on showGroup.group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter is not correct. Please view this [Plunkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/60ZZHpRteeuiwWnOXxx8?p=preview)

Comment: Did this answer help you? Let me know if this answer is incorrect. If this answer is correct and helped you, kindly accept the answer.

Comment: It helped me alot! Thats exactly what i'am looking for! Thank you!

Comment: I have checked your code at Plunkr and it worked, but it is not filtering the Date by group! It look through all element and not only group. Here i modified your example a little bit and now its not working: http://plnkr.co/edit/sltxetiDAXSK3fb7ueS1

Comment: Glad it helped you. I don't really understand what you mean by 'but it is not filtering the Date by group'. I was under the impression you just need to filter ppl by the group they belong to. Anyways, if you think the answer I gave is correct and it helped you, could you kindly mark this answer as the 'accepted answer' as explained here http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235 ?